# multiple treatment in uplift modeling

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I am trying to perform uplift modeling where there are multiple treatment. I came across this package that enables to perform uplift modeling for a single treatment.

https://github.com/wayfair/pylift

But I want extent this for multi treatment. Is there a way to do this

Answer (score 0):

*A caveat: I have not tested this, but it should be theoretically sound.*

You could add a feature (let's call it `x` for convenience) that indicates which treatment is shown, and either:

1. **Duplicate the control rows so each control group member has a row for each different value of `x`.** For example, if you have one observation for person `A` in the control group, but you have 2 treatments and so two values for `x`, `1` and `2`, you would duplicate your observation for person `A` so you have one observation with `x=1` and another with `x=2`. Then adjust your objective function or the Transformed Outcome policy (if that's what you're using) to rectify the bias this creates (more details below).
2. Or if you don't have enough memory, **you could randomly assign values from the possible values of `x` to the control rows**.

If you don't do one of these things, your model won't be able to split on this feature.

If you do (1), you'll need to account for the bias created by having so many more control group members by either modifying your objective function or adjusting the policy value for the Transformed Outcome.

If you are using the Transformed Outcome method, this amounts to just setting `p=1/(1+N)`, where `N` is the number of treatments that you are considering (where the transformed outcome is defined as `(W - p)/(p*(1-p))`). In `pylift`, this amounts to adding a column in your dataframe where the values are `1/(1+N)`, and specifying this in `TransformedOutcome`. I.e., when instantiating the `TransformedOutcome` object, you can add the following argument:

```
TransformedOutcome(col_policy=NAME_OF_COLUMN)
```

---

Alternatively, you could simply make a different model for each treatment against the control. The biggest problem with this, though, is that the values likely will not be comparable. But to give yourself a reasonable chance, I'd make sure you use the same hyperparameters for each model and hopefully have the same amount of data as well (or the hyperparameters being the same will be somewhat meaningless).